# Why addClass not working?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="test1"></label>
    <input type="text" name="test1" class="form-control test1" id="test1" placeholder="" width="200">
</div>
```

For add class for div `<div class="form-group">` i use code:

```
var FindName = arr[i].name; //test1

$("input[name=FindName]").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

But code isnt working. Tell me please where error in my code?

Comment: The `input` doesn't have the `name` of `FindName`. It's `test1`.

Comment: parent dont have a class "test"

Comment: Are you trying to remove the class `test1` from the label or the div?

Comment: Why do you need to use a selector at all? Isn't `arr[i]` a reference to this `<input>` element? Just use `$(arr[i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use that variable the wrong way. Try this:

```
$("input[name=test1]").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

Or if you *must* use the variable, concatenate it:

```
$("input[name=" + FindName + "]").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

Answer (score 2):

`input[name=FindName]` matches elements whose `name` attribute is literally the string `FindName`. If you want to use the `FindName` variable, either construct a new selector:

```
$('input[name="' + FindName + '"]')
```

Or wrap the native DOM method:

```
$(document.getElementsByName(FindName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the concatenating of your variable. If `FindName` is a variable you need to concatenate it into your selector.

Try this:

```
$("input[name='"+FindName+"']").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

string concentanation :

```
var FindName = 'test1';

$("input[name='"+FindName+"']").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

on the other hand, why not just:

```
$('#'+findName).closest('div').removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using your variable `FindName` as a constant string, try change it into:

```
$("input[name='"+FindName+"']").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not selecting the input tag correctly. The input tag has a name set to "test1"

```
$("input[name="+ FindName +"]").parent().removeClass("test").addClass("test2");
```